# Allow laptop to access only 1 LAN network i.e COMPANY.COM

Tags: networking, lan

I have small company, I want my laptops to have internet access only with my company's network, i.e company.com network. I do not want others to take company's laptops to other places and connect other networks via lan cable.

I can allow or block Wi-Fi networks but I need to do this with LAN in this case. LAN cables.

Thanks

Comment: Couldn't you just disable the "Ethernet" adapter through adapter settings?

Comment: If I disable it then they won't be able to use my company's internet - LAN. I want to allow only my LAN network and blacklist all other LANs.

Comment: Pretty sure you can deny all then whitelist your APs MAC address through netsh. Let me go look into that.

Comment: What operating system is running on the laptops? For Windows you can configure via group policy that login waits for network connection to the domain controller. No company domain controller available no login possible.